# How can I send email from my iOS App silently

Tags: objective-c, email, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to send email from my iOS App, without showing native `mailComposeController`.

I want to fill its email text body and other attributes at back end, I know this is possible but my question is how can I send email without presenting `mailComposeController` instead of on just the button click(my email sent).

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Try this solution : http://sugartin.info/2011/10/13/sending-a-mail-useing-gmail/

Comment: Thanks for the link its helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, since this will be a breach of privacy.
For example you could get the user e-mail address without their consent.

An option would be to create your own API to send the e-mail or send it via SMTP directly.

Comment: That's not necessarily the case.  If, for example, you are running an enterprise device on a company-owned device with the proper policies in place, it would be appropriate.